# Split url what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to split an URL so it just returns the parameters i want

```
 www.example.com/?v=12345 

 newurl = newurl.replace('www.example.com/?v=', '').split('=');
```

Shouldn't that return '12345'? It is returning '2' though.

How can i return '12345' ?

Thanks guys

Comment: For starters, `.split()` returns an array so it's never going to return a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already used replace() function replace the url, here you get your expected output. There is no need of splitting for one query parameter, Try this,

```
 var newurl="www.example.com/?v=12345";
 newurl = newurl.replace('www.example.com/?v=', '');
 console.log(newurl);//output 12345
 alert(newurl);
```

Comment: shouldn't there be a test of `if(window.console)` before logging anything ?

Comment: No, there is no need. You can see the in browser console tab.

Comment: or `alert(newurl);` it helps!

Comment: if the browser does not have any console(i.e. IE), the javascript code might not run.

Comment: Am not interested to working with ie, personally i dont like that even, it is dead rubber

Comment: What is about the OP ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `split` part.

A more bulletproof example would be to do it like that:

```
newurl = newurl.split('=')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You want just the parameter? Then:

```
var url = "www.example.com/?v=12345";
var param = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=')+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are really wanting to do is get the query string parameters from a URL, there are many examples around the net, like this one here, which will parse them into a map for you.

#### Example URL

`http://example.com?name=Cory`

#### Example Code

```
function extractQueryString() {
    var oResult = {};
    var aQueryString = (location.search.substr(1)).split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < aQueryString.length; i++) {
        var aTemp = aQueryString[i].split("=");
        if (aTemp[1].length > 0) {
            oResult[aTemp[0]] = unescape(aTemp[1]);
        }
    }
    return oResult;
}
```

#### Example Usage

```
var qs = extractQueryString();
qs.name   // outputs 'Cory'
```

#### Reference

http://joncom.be/code/javascript-querystring-values/

Comment: I think a little bit much for my case but thank you !